# fragment getView() method is NULL in FragmentTransaction

Tags: android

I have two `fragment` inside a `LinearLayout`.
When I click on a FAB button I would like to hide one but a
 null object reference appears on `FragmentTransaction` hide method.
Why doesn't "f" have a view reference?

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    public FragmentOne() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View returnView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        FloatingActionButton fabTemp = returnView.findViewById(R.id.fabTemp);

        final Fragment f = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0).getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(1);
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        fabTemp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {

              transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                android.R.animator.fade_out);

                if (f.isHidden()) {
                    transaction.show(f);
                } else {
                    transaction.hide(f);
                }
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });

        return returnView;
    }
```

I solved in another way despite not being as i wanted

final View frag = getView().findViewById(R.id.frgSettemp);

frag.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: What exactly you trying to with this `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0).getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(1);`?

Comment: You can get the fragment by id and hide and show as per your requirement like this. getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.yourFragmentId)

Comment: with getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0) i get the parentFragment(FragmentOne) but i want to get one of the two children (FragmentSetTemp). Infact with that string i get the child.

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreateView` just inflate and return the view.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View returnView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        return returnView;
    }
```

Try the other processing in `onViewCreated` `@override` method. like this

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);


        FloatingActionButton fabTemp = getView().findViewById(R.id.fabTemp);

        final Fragment f = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        fabTemp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

        transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                android.R.animator.fade_out);

                if (f.isHidden()) {
                    transaction.show(f);
                } else {
                    transaction.hide(f);
                }
                transaction.commit();
             }
        });

}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: same error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ViewGroup.startViewTransition(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

Comment: ok it works but it hides the parent,children and fab.... I want to hide only one of the two children...

Comment: Set debugger on this line  `final Fragment f = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0).getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(1); ` and wait some time and then go for next execution. Please try this.

Comment: as you can see f contains the fragment i want but when i resume and press on fab it gives me this error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ViewGroup.startViewTransition(android.view.View)' on a null object reference     [IMG]http://i67.tinypic.com/w89k06.png[/IMG]

Answer (score 0):

You should call only

```
final Fragment f = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
```

or

```
final Fragment f = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(1);
```

What you have done will return null for sure.

Comment: see last answer i gave to Faysal Ahmed